# Join reorders results

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there any particular reason why adding an additional join to an ordered table would reorder the result set?

Using a left join on the existing result set

table-valued function is similar to below (function returns @table):

```
conditional
    BEGIN
        INSERT @table
               (col1)
        select col1 from table1
        order by col1, x, y
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT @table
               (col1)
        select col1 from table1
        order by col1, x, y, z
    END
```

Comment: Flagged as a duplicate because the best answer is in that question. Unless you explicitly ask for the result set in a certain order, there is no guarantee it will always appear in that order.

Comment: In case anyone was wondering: To be able to have the conditional ordering, I wound up just using some case statements for the order by's for the set created post join

Comment: And in SQL Server 2012 you'll find that even the order you observed without the join [will likely no longer appear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222043/table-valued-function-order-by-is-ignored-in-output/11231935#11231935).

Comment: @MartinSmith was in 2014, however the order without the join was maintained somehow?

Answer (score 3):

**There is no inherent order inside a table.**

There is no pre-stablished order when you insert rows. If run for example the following query:

```
SELECT A.A, B.B
FROM   tblA A
       JOIN tblB B ON A.id = B.id
```

Without an `ORDER BY`, then no particular order will be used. If you want some particular sorted results, you must use an `ORDER BY` clause. You could use a primary key and sort according to its values for example. And doesn't matter if you add one or more `JOIN` to the statement, same answer, without `ORDER BY` you are not assure to get same order each time you run the query.

There are several questions/answers that could help you to get a better understanding of this particular point:

- a really deep and detailed answer here on dba.stackexchange.com: [Storage order vs Result order](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/19222/9031)
- [You cannot guarantee the order unless you specifically provide an order by with the query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15766414/1297603)
- [In the SQL world, order is not an inherent property of a set of data.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5775/9031)
- [Without ORDER BY, You Can’t Depend On the Order of Results](http://michaeljswart.com/2013/09/without-order-by-you-cant-depend-on-the-order-of-results/) great blog entry by Michael J. Swart

Comment: So I have a table-valued function that outputs a table in a specified order (order specified within function) upon left join a table, the results are reordered. Thoughts?

Comment: @Drew sounds about right. You're not ordering the overall result set, so there is no guarantee of the result order

Comment: As @MarkSinkinson points out, doesn't matter that the table-valued function returns a table with a specified order. Once you run the "outter" select without `ORDER BY` you are not guarantee to have same order on each run.

Comment: @Drew How does the table-valued function indicate an ORDER BY? Because it also includes TOP? That ORDER BY only indicates which rows to include in the TOP, not how to present them. If you use silly tricks like TOP 100 PERCENT the optimizer actually discards both the TOP and the ORDER BY because it knows they are meaningless. It works the same way [in a view](https://sqlblog.org/2020/05/12/bad-habits-to-kick-relying-on-undocumented-behavior) - if you want an order, you need to specify that order on the OUTER query, not inside a view or function.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, something similar to what I posted above!

Comment: @Drew well that's even less reliable. Why do you think order of insert = order of subsequent select (never mind when combining with other data)?

Comment: @AaronBertrand ha. And good question, I'm guessing the records are not just inserted willy-nilly?

Also, as far as I could tell the records returned by the tvf were in the correct order--coincidence or was it not working from the top down? Or maybe a better question is I guess it's just dependent on whatever the optimal insert sequence would be?

Comment: There is no such thing as "top-down" - you need to think about a table (even a table variable inside a tvf, which you should avoid and use an inline tvf vs. multi-statement tvf anyway) as an unordered bag of rows. Think about this: I'm in a room and drop a bunch of marbles on the floor. You enter the room, can you tell me which marble hit the floor first? No. If I paid attention, you could ask me, and I could hand you the marbles in that order. This is why you need to add an outer ORDER BY *and* have some column that can actually indicate the order you want.